# Faster way to for $z^3 = -2 (1+i \sqrt 3) \bar z$ than complex algebra

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

What is the fastest way to solve for $z^3 = -2 (1+i \sqrt 3) \bar z$?

I know how to do this using complex algebra. but that takes a long time.
Can someone show me a faster way?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! You should take a look at http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation to see how to typeset MathJax equations on this site. It can greatly improve readability.

Comment: Writing $z$ in polar form and using $1+i \sqrt3=2\exp(i\pi/3)$ yields a one-line proof, no?

Comment: Please show me. I'm confused @Did

Comment: How do I write it in polar form

Comment: @user3924310 Every complex number can be represented as
$$z = a + bi = r e^{i\phi}$$
Where $r = |z| = \sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ and $\phi = \arg z = \arctan \frac ba$

Answer (score 1):

Taking the modulus, $|z|^3=2\cdot2\cdot|z|$, and $|z|=0$ or $|z|=2$ ($|z|=-2$ cannot hold).

Taking the argument, $3\arg z=\pi+\pi/3-\arg z+2k\pi$, and $\arg z=\pi/3+k\pi/2$.

$$z=0,1+i\sqrt3,-\sqrt3+i,-1-i\sqrt3,\sqrt3-i.$$

Answer (score 0):

Multiply by $z$ to obtain $z^4 = -2 (1+i\sqrt 3)|z|^2$. Looking at absolute values we see that $|z|^2 = \sqrt{4 + 4 \cdot 3} = \sqrt{16} = 4$, finally looking at angles we have
$$4 \arg z = \arg (-1-i\sqrt 3) = -\frac{2\pi}3$$
Combined we get $z = |z| e^{i\arg z} = 2 e^{-i\frac{\pi}6 + k \frac\pi2} = (1-\sqrt 3i) \cdot e^{\frac{ik\pi}2}$ where $k\in\{0,1,2,3\}$ so all in all
$$z = \pm(1\pm \sqrt3 i)$$
And of course the trivial solution $z=0$.

---

Note that I used a few equalities: $\arg zw \equiv \arg z + \arg w \pmod{2\pi}$, $|z| = \sqrt{\Re^2 z + \Im^2 z} = \sqrt{z\bar z}$ and $\exp(i\frac\pi6) = \frac12(1+\sqrt3 i).$

Comment: How did you get the 4+4+3 can you show some more steps? thanks

Comment: What is arg? not sure if i have been taught this

Comment: $|z|^2 = |-2(1+i\sqrt 3)| = |-2 - 2\sqrt 3 i| = \sqrt{4 + 4 \cdot 3}$

Comment: $\arg$ is the argument (or angle) of a complex number. In polar form
$$\arg (r e^{i\phi}) \equiv \phi \pmod{2\pi}$$
This congruence is also where the factor $e^{\frac{ik\pi}2}$ comes from